# How to append from file into list in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, append

I have a sample file called 'scores.txt' which holds the following values:

```
10,0,6,3,7,4
```

I want to be able to somehow take each value from the line, and append it to a list so that it becomes `sampleList = [10,0,6,3,7,4]`.

I have tried doing this using the following code below,

```
score_list = []

opener = open('scores.txt','r')

for i in opener:
    score_list.append(i)

print (score_list)
```

which partially works, but for some reason, it doesn't do it properly. It just sticks all the values into one index instead of separate indexes. How can I make it so all the values get put into their own separate index?

Comment: You have a `list`, not an array. The latter is [something different in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have CSV data (comma separated). Easiest is to use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

all_values = []

with open('scores.txt', newline='') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        all_values.extend(row)
```

Otherwise, split the values. Each line you read is a string with the `','` character between the digits:

```
all_values = []

with open('scores.txt', newline='') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        all_values.extend(line.strip().split(','))
```

Either way, `all_values` ends up with a list of *strings*. If all your values are only consisting of digits, you could convert these to integers:

```
all_values.extend(map(int, row))
```

or

```
all_values.extend(map(int, line.strip().split(',')))
```

Comment: Using the first solution that you provided gives me a `Line 13 in reader = csv(infile): TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` error. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: @TeeKayM: because I'm a numpty and forgot the `.reader` part.

Answer (score 3):

That is an efficient way how to do that without using any external package:

```
with open('tmp.txt','r') as f:
    score_list = f.readline().rstrip().split(",")

# Convert to list of int
score_list = [int(v) for v in score_list]

print score_list
```

Comment: Definitely helpful. Can I just ask: What does the '.rstrip()' and '.split() ' functions do? Thanks

Comment: Sure, `rstrip` function removes line endings and `split(",")` separates a string on ","

Answer (score 2):

Just use `split` on comma on each line and add the returned list to your `score_list`, like below:

```
opener = open('scores.txt','r')
score_list = []

for line in opener:
    score_list.extend(map(int,line.rstrip().split(',')))

print( score_list )
```

Comment: You should really use `score_list.extend()` or use `score_list += ` to avoid creating new lists all the time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. Updated my answer to use `extend`